# how to prevent WAR file modification in deployment

Tags: jboss, code-signing

this is regarding the WAR file deployment in jboss 14. I should proposal a code sign framwork in deployment.

Comment: jboss 14 doesn't exist. Could you please explain more precisely what is your question ?

Comment: My concern is integrity of war files before sending to customer.